# 404 error with GET request with correct credentials

Tags: javascript, request

I have switched my node package to the official shopify-api-node one and now the request isn't working it returns a 404 error.

The requests parameters seem to be fine after looking at the docs, and the shopName, access token etc are also correct i used the identical ones for the last package, (shopify-node-api) which i only stopped using because it returned a body in a strange coded language so i couldnt check it for errors, anyway here is the code:

The 'name' value is the order number by the way.

```
 getOrderByNum: (req, res) => {
    // const domain = req.params.domain;
    const domain = 'chatbotdemo.myshopify.com'
    const name = req.params.name;
    console.log(req.body)
    db.getStoreTocken(domain, (result) => {
          const shopify = new Shopify({
            shopName: domain,
            accessToken: result, 
            autoLimit: true
          });

         shopify.order.get(name)
         .then(order => {

            console.log('console the order??!?!?!');
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('error??' + err));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

the shopify docs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node

Comment: http 404 stands for Bad URL... are you sure you are pointing to correct url? missing http? https?

Comment: Yes because when I remove '.get' and replace it with list, which returns ALL of the orders, it works

Comment: My only worry is that they want the orderID and not the orderNumber in the request which would suck for me